# Change http status 503 to 200 for app_offline.htm

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, app-offline.htm

I have integrated in to my .net application that when I want to take my site offline, I place a app_offline file at the root of my web application, as outlined here [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx)

This results in a 503 status code being returned for all requests to the web application, showing the app offline page.

This resulted in an issue for me where my load balancer sees a 503 status code and takes the site out of the load balancer.

Is there any way I can change the app_offline.htm file to return a 200 status code?